# Numerical integration of functions sampled with constant and non-constant rates

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximate-integration

I have arbitrary functions of time $y(t)$ (sin, linear, sawtooth, triangular, etc) with two types of data sampling, namely constant sampling rate and variable sampling rate (in some parts the function has a denser collection of values than in other parts).

I would like to know:

1. Is there a numerical method to integrate a function with constant sampling rate. Is there a numerical method to integrate a function with variable sampling rate with the best accuracy ?
2. If I integrate both functions with constant and variable sampling rate, will I get about the same results?

Below I'm showing an example of the same function $y(t)$ with constant and variable sampling rates.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. There are several approaches for evaluating integrals of uniformly sampled functions, the simplest ones being *Newton-Cotes* quadrature formulas. You can easily find numerical integration approaches in books on numerical methods, see for example N.S. Bakhvalov, *Numerical Methods*, Mir Publishers Moscrow, 1981. Although sophisticated integration rules consist of optimizing the quadrature nodes, I do not think this is your case, as you do not mention any particular rule for choosing quadrature nodes. In this case ("random" sampling), I would suggest using some form of interpolation to "resample" the non-uniformly sampled function $y(t)$ to a regular grid and then applying quadrature approaches for uniformly sampled functions (constant rate).
2. If you decide to apply the interpolation+quadrature scheme, then, for a fixed applied numerical integration technique, I would expect to achieve better accuracy for functions having constant sampling rate, because in this case you will not experience interpolation errors.